# printing list elements in python with a single line code

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am new to Python. I would to print all elements in list using a single line of code. You may use lambda function.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for each in a:
    print(each)
```

Here, I used two lines of code
What I want is a single line of code to get the same output
(preferably lambda function)

output required:

1

2

3

4

Comment: Why preferably a lambda function?

Comment: `print(*a, sep='\n')`

Comment: Possibly better suited for code golf.

Answer (score 3):

Try this just using `print`:

```
print(*a, sep=' ')
```

print accepts `sep` key that will put between printing of each element of an iterable.

so the above code output will be

```
1 2 3 4
```

You can use `','` or `\n`(new line) to print between each charater.

it means:

```
print(*a, sep='\n')
```

output will be:

```
1
2
3 
4
```

Comment: I dont want output on single line but the code on single line.

Comment: like for each in a: print a

Comment: @KRISHNAI I already told you the solution. but I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `lambda` AT ANY PRICE, then (using Python 3):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
list(map(lambda x:print(x),a))
```

However, if one liner is enough for you keep in mind that such code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for each in a: print(each)
```

is legal Python code, producing same result.
Yet another option is converting `int` to `str` and joining them:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str,a)))
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I want to use lambda is because my program has lot of for loops of printing lists. Anyway thanks above mentioned methods are helpful to me

Answer (score -1):

Try this
print(''.join(map(str, a)))